# Нахождение минимального ряда в двумерном массиве

Tags: массивы, алгоритм

Сама задача:

Задается размер матрицы целых чисел размером M на N. 
Вывести строку, в которой сумма элементов минимальна. 
Если таких строк несколько, то вывести одну любую. `N, M ∈ [1, 100]`

Помогите составить алгоритм, который решит мою задачу.

Comment: вы можете написать цикл по первому уровню? а можете посчитать сумму элементов на втором уровне в отдельно взятой строке? Можете эту сумму сравнить с имеющимся минимумом? можете если найден новый минимум, сохранить индекс? Можете после всех циклов вывести строку по сохраненному индексу? в чем сложность то здесь может быть?

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм примерно следующий:

```
min_sum = 0
index = 0

for i = 0 to N - 1
  min_sum = min_sum + matrix[0, i]

for i = 1 to M - 1
  current_sum = 0
  for j = 1 to N - 1
    current_sum = current_sum + matrix[i, j]
  if current_sum < min_sum
    min_sum = current_sum
    index = i

print index
```

Если матрица задается с клавиатуры, то есть смысл считать сумму сразу по завершению ввода каждой строки.